# JSF datatable - method always gets called with last element in datatable

Tags: jsf, el

I have component thats basically datatable made of list of buttons. Each button opens dialog thats another component, and passes current var of datatable to this component (dialog). Inside dialog there is button that submits element and text. This command button has actionListener=#{beanClass.beanMethod(cc.attrs.passedListElement)}. Problem is element passed to method is always last element in datatable, even if i click in middle element of datatable. Why its happening?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]